# How to make a HTML5 form responsive?

Tags: css, html

I have a form as in the below code ? how can i make it fit to the center of the screen and convert it to be responsive ?

HTML5 Code

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"     
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>CSS3 Search Form</title>
<link href="css/cbdb-search-form.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" />
<style type="text/css">

body {
background: #999;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<form id="search-form">
<input type="email" />
<input type="submit" value="Login" /> 
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS Code

/****************************************
    CSS 3 SEARCH BY ZEAOS
****************************************/

```
#search-form {
background: #e1e1e1; /* Fallback color for non-css3 browsers */
width: 365px;

/* Gradients */
background: -webkit-gradient( linear,left top, left bottom, color-stop(0, rgb(243,243,243)), color-stop(1, rgb(225,225,225)));
background: -moz-linear-gradient( center top, rgb(243,243,243) 0%, rgb(225,225,225) 100%);

/* Rounded Corners */
border-radius: 17px; 
-webkit-border-radius: 17px;
-moz-border-radius: 17px;

/* Shadows */
box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.3), 0 0 2px rgba(0,0,0,.3); 
-webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.3), 0 0 2px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
-moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.3), 0 0 2px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
}

/*** TEXT BOX ***/
input[type="email"]{
background: #fafafa; /* Fallback color for non-css3 browsers */

/* Gradients */
background: -webkit-gradient( linear, left bottom, left top, color-stop(0, rgb(250,250,250)), color-stop(1, rgb(230,230,230)));
background: -moz-linear-gradient( center top, rgb(250,250,250) 0%, rgb(230,230,230) 100%);

border: 0;
border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
border-right: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,.8);
font-size: 16px;
margin: 4px;
padding: 5px;
width: 250px;

/* Rounded Corners */
border-radius: 17px; 
-webkit-border-radius: 17px;
-moz-border-radius: 17px;

/* Shadows */
box-shadow: -1px -1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.3), 0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
-webkit-box-shadow: -1px -1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.3), 0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
-moz-box-shadow: -1px -1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.3), 0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}

/*** USER IS FOCUSED ON TEXT BOX ***/
input[type="text"]:focus{
outline: none;
background: #fff; /* Fallback color for non-css3 browsers */

/* Gradients */
background: -webkit-gradient( linear, left bottom, left top, color-stop(0, rgb(255,255,255)),  color-stop(1, rgb(235,235,235)));
background: -moz-linear-gradient( center top, rgb(255,255,255) 0%, rgb(235,235,235) 100%);
}

/*** SEARCH BUTTON ***/
input[type="submit"]{
background: #44921f;/* Fallback color for non-css3 browsers */

/* Gradients */
background: -webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0, rgb(79,188,32)),   color-stop(0.15, rgb(73,157,34)), color-stop(0.88, rgb(62,135,28)), color-stop(1, rgb(49,114,21)));
background: -moz-linear-gradient( center top, rgb(79,188,32) 0%, rgb(73,157,34) 15%,   rgb(62,135,28) 88%, rgb(49,114,21) 100%);

border: 0;
color: #eee;
cursor: pointer;
float: right;
font: 16px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-weight: bold;
height: 30px;
margin: 4px 4px 0;
text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.3);
width: 84px;
outline: none;

/* Rounded Corners */
border-radius: 30px; 
-webkit-border-radius: 30px;
-moz-border-radius: 30px;

/* Shadows */
box-shadow: -1px -1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,.5), 1px 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.4);
-moz-box-shadow: -1px -1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,.5), 1px 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.2);
-webkit-box-shadow: -1px -1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,.5), 1px 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.4);
}
/*** SEARCH BUTTON HOVER ***/
input[type="submit"]:hover {
background: #4ea923; /* Fallback color for non-css3 browsers */

/* Gradients */
background: -webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0, rgb(89,222,27)),      color-stop(0.15, rgb(83,179,38)), color-stop(0.8, rgb(66,143,27)), color-stop(1, rgb(54,120,22)));
background: -moz-linear-gradient( center top, rgb(89,222,27) 0%, rgb(83,179,38) 15%,     rgb(66,143,27) 80%, rgb(54,120,22) 100%);
}
input[type="submit"]:active {
background: #4ea923; /* Fallback color for non-css3 browsers */

/* Gradients */
background: -webkit-gradient( linear, left bottom, left top, color-stop(0, rgb(89,222,27)),   
color-stop(0.15, rgb(83,179,38)), color-stop(0.8, rgb(66,143,27)), color-stop(1,  rgb(54,120,22)));
background: -moz-linear-gradient( center bottom, rgb(89,222,27) 0%, rgb(83,179,38) 15%,         rgb(66,143,27) 80%, rgb(54,120,22) 100%);
}
```

**EDIT 1**

This is a mobile web application . Users consists of both smart phones and oldest devices.

Comment: `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"     
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">` is not the HTML5 doctype :) use `<!DOCTYPE html>` and remove `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en"`

Answer (score 4):

### First at all

Remove HTML DOCTYPE or change it to `<!DOCTYPE html>`. HTML5 is not based on SGML, and therefore does not require a reference to a DTD.

### To center Content

Wrap your form in a DIV

```
<body>
<div class="modal">
<form id="search-form">
<input type="email" />
<input type="submit" value="Login" /> 
</form>
</div>
</body>
```

Then Apply this CSS to center on screen.

```
.modal {
   position: fixed;   
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
   transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#search-form {
   position: absolute;
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
   transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

### To be Responsive Use [CSS Media Query](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/CSS/Media_queries)

Media Queries let you apply styles depending on conditions (screen size, screen type, etc) on the screen where you will see the page.

This is only a simple example. I recommend you read about CSS Media Queries.

In this case you set minimum width and height

```
@media ( max-width :320px) {
    .modal {
         min-width: 200px;
         min-height: 120px;
    }
}

@media ( min-width :321px) {
    .modal {
         min-width: 300px;
         min-height: 220px;
    }
}

@media ( min-width :640px) {
    .modal {
         min-width: 480px;
         min-height: 320px;
    }
}

@media ( min-width :1200px) {
    .modal {
         min-width: 700px;
         min-height: 400px;
    }
}
```

### In the other Hand

Have you thought about using [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com)?

[Enjoy!](http://jsfiddle.net/rnrlabs/kqdzLe23/)

Comment: can you please add a jsfiddle for this ?

Comment: resize the results panel to see how to it works. http://jsfiddle.net/rnrlabs/kqdzLe23/

Comment: How can the input be at the center of the screen, both horizontal and vertical using the above code only ?

Comment: @user3592479 the first time I did not understand well what you want. now I think so. see the fiddle again

Comment: This is good, how can i add an image as background to the screen, behind the inout box Image URL http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-VW8_PcOFfpk/UfJvjztjYjI/AAAAAAAAAfU/4wrx_NNwGJ0/s1600/Charminar+night+view.jpg

Comment: Your question did not say anything about the background. If needed please consider making another question. Anyway I commented that you can use the CSS background property "background: url (/path/to/image.png); background-size: cover;" in the body.

Comment: Thanks , but the image is nt responsive ? also how can i use the same css for the input email box and submit button ?

Answer (score 1):

First of all for making a responsive form or anything like that always give `width` in %age followed by giving media queries. You can use bootstrap for making your page even better. you can get bootstrap from getbootstrap.com/. The usage and implementation techniques are mentioned there

Answer (score 0):

To center, add

```
width: 365px;
height:38px;

position:absolute;
top:50%;
margin-top:-19px;
left:50%;
margin-left:-182px;
```

in #search-form

for responsive, this could be a starting point:

```
    @media all and (max-width:480px) {

#search-form {
    width:100%;
    margin-left:-50%;
}

input[type="email"]{
    width:70%;
}

input[type="submit"]{
    width:20%;
}

}
```

Comment: it only centered horizontally , how to make it vertical center also

Answer (score 0):

To center add position:relative to the **body**

Then you add these rules to the #form  to your css:

```
#search-form{
  margin:auto;
  position:absolute;
  z-index: 30;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  width: 300px; /*variable*/
  height: 300px;  /*variable*/
        }
```

Comment: adding the above code resulted as in screenshot http://s27.postimg.org/imdqzxeib/loginbox.png